# Book about dragons

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I'm trying to remember this story about dragons, where a guy and his companion, a dragon, travel through forest around the country. Something about gold being their interest. Towards the end of the book, there is a dragon egg in a cave near the ocean. Sorry I can't give more clues.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Please do take a look, because it will be quite difficult to find with the lack of details

Answer (score 5):

Could it be [*Eragon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon) (aka the Inheritance Cycle)?

> a guy and his companion, a dragon, travel through forest around the country.

Eragon's constant companion is a blue dragon named [Saphira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Inheritance_Cycle_characters#Saphira). A lot of the books involve their travels through the forests of Alagaësia.

> Something about gold being their interest.

[Glaedr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Inheritance_Cycle_characters#Characters_from_Du_Weldenvarden) is a gold dragon, and the cover of the [third book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisingr). Eragon and Saphira go to great lengths to travel and meet him. Their eventual meeting is very important to the story.

> Towards the end of the book, there is a dragon egg in a cave near the ocean.

In the [fourth book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(Paolini_novel)) of the "trilogy," Eragon and Saphira find a lot of dragon eggs in a cave on an island (Vroengard Island), which used to be the Dragon Riders' base of operations.

Comment: If someone could please let me know if/when the question is updated, so I can edit my post as necessary. Thanks :)

Comment: I admit that the gold connection is a little weak. This answer was primarily my brother's idea.